# Improving performance of OpenGL rendering: rendering multiple times from different POVs

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on an application that needs to render the scene from multiple points of view. I notice that if I render once, even if the frag shader is long and complicated (writing to multiple 3D textures) it runs at 65 FPS. As soon as I add another rendering pass before that (simply rendering to 2 targets, colour and normals+depth) the framerate drops to 40. If I add a shadowmap pass it drops even further to 25-30 FPS. What is the best way to cope with multiple renderings and still retain a high framerate?

Right now I have 1 shader for doing both the normal+depth map and the shadowmap, 1 shader to write to 3d textures and 1 shader to do the final rendering by reading from all the maps. If I run only the last shader (hence reading gibberish values for nomral+depth and shadowmap) it runs at 65 FPS (and the calculations is simply a series of operations, no loops or conditionals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measuring FPS can be misleading. 65 FPS corresponds to 15ms per frame whereas 40 FPS corresponds to 25ms per frame. 30 FPS corresponds to 33ms per frame.

So, the complicated shader alone takes 15ms, and the complicated shader plus switching rendertargets plus switching shaders plus doing the actual processing of the second render pass takes an additional 10ms. That's not bad at all, the normal/depth shader takes 1/3 less time, which is pretty much "as expected". The shadow map adds another 8ms.

Unless you have noticeable pipeline stalls, rendering is nowadays first and foremost limited  by ROP, which means nothing else but the more pixels you touch the more time it takes, proportionally.

Of course, 15ms is already a quite heavy frame time unless the scene is *massive*, you should make sure that you do not have a lot of stalls due to shader and texture changes (which break batches), and you should make sure that you don't stall because of buffer syncs.

Try to batch together draw calls, and be sure to avoid state changes. That will make sure the GPU doesn't go idle in between. The cost of state changes, in decreasing order of importance, is (courtesy of Cass Everitt):

1. Render target
2. Shader
3. ROP
4. Texture
5. Vertex Format
6. UBO/Vertex buffer bindings
7. Uniform updates

It seems like you can't avoid the render target change (since you have two of them) but in fact you can render to two targets at the same time. Sorting by shader (before sorting by texture or other stuff) may avoid those state changes, etc. etc.

Comment: This answer might be very helpful in my case, cause I programmed everything hoping just to see it work, nothing was even slightly optimised. The thing that I suspect being the bottleneck is the fact that I am using 5 FBOs, one with 2 targets, one for the shadowmap and 3 for the 3d textures. Maybe I should start by narrowing down to a single FBO with 6 targets. Also the fact that I am writing and reading on so many different textures might be another big bottleneck

Comment: btw the scene is medium sized, it's the crytek sponza and i am currently voxelising it, doing the other 2 renderings and then doing raymarching.

Comment: I also noticed that doing this glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, volumeFbo[i]);
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); a bunch of time kills the performance

Comment: Well yes, changing rendertarget is (1) in the list. It's the most expensive of all state changes.

Comment: Another thing I noticed now that I am debugging using Nsight. I have frequent calls like this: bindtexture(tex=10); drawElemBaseVert...; bindtexture(tex=11); drawElemBaseVert...; bindtexture(tex=10); drawElemBaseVert...; bindtexture(tex=12); drawElemBaseVert...; bindtexture(tex=10); drawElemBaseVert...;

Comment: and this happens a lot. Would it be wise to sort all the elements by texture object so that i bind texture 1 and draw everything in 1 call, then tex 2 etc?

Comment: Yes, sorting is one approach. Another one would be to index into an array texture (on GL 3+).

Comment: i am using 4.3 so I will try it. Do you have any quick link on how to use it? Thanks

Comment: sorry if i bother you again. What you saying is that I create the texture array and store all the textures there. Then, at the loading of the model, based on the texture object, i somehow link the element I will have to draw to the index in the texture array. When I actually have to draw I loop through the textures in the array, bind the texture (or not?) and recall the elements and draw them. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: You just use the w coordinate as index in addition to u and v. The array texture combines several nomal textures into one (which you only bind once at tbe beginning). If memory is a problem, you can combine this with sparse textures, see GDC2013 talk by Everitt.

Comment: @Damon what does ROP mean?

Comment: @JustinMeiners https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_Operations_Pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the geometry you are rendering in the geometry shader, and perform whatever transformations you require.  You will only need to make one render pass this way.

More info: http://www.geeks3d.com/20111117/simple-introduction-to-geometry-shader-in-glsl-part-2/

Comment: The vertex shader cannot duplicate geometry, you probably mean the geometry shader. This works, but does not address the OP's problem (or the perceived problem).

Comment: Thanks, fixed!  However, I don't see why the OP can't avoid the render target change / second render pass using this method.